# Callee taking action based on type of caller

Tags: oop

I would like to know if there is some alternate better pattern other than below where an object passes itself as a context to another object which in turn uses the context or lack as logic to build the necessary output. I have tried making the caller/sender an interface and pass itself as an interface but the real question is is it good practice for the called object to even know who its caller is, i.e. to distinguish it from other callers and take separate actions if necessary? Am I missing a piece to the puzzle?

```
Caller (CGQuery):
        public string RenderForLoop()
        {
...
            sb.Append(string.Join("",this.ContentIsCGExpressions.Select(exp => exp.GetProcessedExpression(this))));
...

Callee (CGExpression):
        public string GetProcessedExpression(object context = null)
        {
...
           retv = ReplaceCodes(retv, context);
...
        private string ReplaceCodes(string retv, object context = null)
        {
...            retv = ReplaceContextSequenceCode(retv, context);
            return retv;
        }
...
        private string ReplaceContextSequenceCode(string retv, object context = null)
        {
            var _regx = new Regex("(?i)<q_ctx_seq>");
            var _matchresult = _regx.Match(retv);
            while (_matchresult.Success)
            {
                string replacement = FetchContextSequenceQueryTableFieldExpression(context);
                retv = retv.Replace(_matchresult.Groups[0].Value, replacement);
                _matchresult = _matchresult.NextMatch();
            }
            return retv;
        }

        private string FetchContextSequenceQueryTableFieldExpression(object context = null)
        {

            if (context != null && context is CGQuery)
            {
                return ((CGQuery)context).FetchContextSequenceQueryTableFieldExpression();
            }
            return this.CGStatementsUsedAsParamsFor.Any() ?
                this.CGStatementsUsedAsParamsFor.Single().FetchContextSequenceQueryTableFieldExpression(context) 
                :
                this.CGQueriesContentFor.Single().FetchContextSequenceQueryTableFieldExpression();
        }
```

It's this line in the above that I'm concerned about (seems to violate encapsulation?)

```
        if (context != null && context is CGQuery)
        {
            return ((CGQuery)context).FetchContextSequenceQueryTableFieldExpression();
        }
```

sorry I don't know how to highlight the code in the main block.

Answer (score 0):

What about letting the caller deliver an object to the callee containing the action to execute? The caller may be queried within this action without the callee being aware of its existence.

Generally I would say it's not good OOP practice to decide behaviour on the class of the calling object.

Comment: I considered a delegate as you say; so are you saying a delegate should be a non-optional parameter of GetProcessedExpression? Or maybe I'm getting it all wrong and GetProcessedExpression is too generic an entry point. Perhaps there should be some other class in between this caller and callee?...

Comment: In fact I thought more of a **Strategy Pattern** or a **Visitor**, depending on the control flow. **Delegation** would mean to just hand ovre the task to another class (like a central service or similar). In this case here you would hand over the object itself responsible for executing the desired action.